# In Moose, how do you declare predicate and clearer methods when defining multiple attributes?

Tags: perl, moose

In Moose you can declare a group of attributes at once, assuming the initialization parameters are the same:

```
has [qw( foo bar baz )] => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Str',
    required => 1,
);
```

This is a lovely feature that saves a ton of typing.  However, I find myself puzzled about how define a predicate, clearer or even a builder method using this syntax.

```
has 'foo' => (
    is        => 'ro',
    isa       => 'Str',
    required  => 1,
    clearer   => 'clear_foo',
    predicate => 'has_foo',
);
```

Is there a parameter I can use that will build standard 'has_X`, 'clear_X` and `_build_X` methods for all the attributes in my list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
has $_ => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Str',
    required => 1,
    clearer => '_clear_' . $_,
    # etc...
) for (qw(foo bar baz);
```

Note that `lazy_build => 1` will automatically generate clearers, and
predicates, but they will always be public, which is starting to be frowned
upon in the Moose community. (I don't think anyone's blogged about this yet,
but it's been a topic of conversation on IRC #moose of late.)

Comment: I should have thought of this.  Just because `has` looks like a declaration, doesn't mean it isn't executable code.

Comment: A niggly style issue, but I'd make this "foreach (qw(foo bar baz)) {...}". The attribute names crop up a little late in the game in the answer's code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

```
lazy_build => 1,
```

That also marks them lazy, but [that's recommended](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose%3a%3aManual%3a%3aAttributes#Laziness) for attributes with a builder.

Comment: You can specify lazy build by using `lazy => 1`.  Then you can specifically declare if you want predicate and/or clearer.